# Creating a table in pdf file using PDF::Report and PDF::Report::Table

Tags: perl

In one of my application having a requirement to download a PDF file with report details in form of table.

For creating a PDF file and writing a table in it, using cpan module available in perl. PDF::Report and PDF::Report::Table.

Please find below the code sample:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use PDF::Report;
use PDF::Report::Table;

my $pdf   = PDF::Report->new( PageSize => 'A4', PageOrientation => 'Portrait' );
my $table = PDF::Report::Table->new( $pdf );

my $data = [
['A1' , 'B1' , 'C1'],
['A2' , 'B2' , 'C2'],
['A3' , 'B3' , 'C3'],
['A4' , 'B4' , 'C4'],
['A5' , 'B5' , 'C5'],
['A6' , 'B6' , 'C6'],
['A7' , 'B7' , 'C7'],
['A8' , 'B8' , 'C8'],
['A9' , 'B9' , 'C9'],
['A10' , 'B10' , 'C10'],
['A11' , 'B11' , 'C11'],
['A12' , 'B12' , 'C12'],
['A13' , 'B13' , 'C13'],
['A14' , 'B14' , 'C14'],
['A15' , 'B15' , 'C15'],
['A16' , 'B16' , 'C16'],
['A17' , 'B17' , 'C17'],
['A18' , 'B18' , 'C18'],
['A19' , 'B19' , 'C19'],
['A20' , 'B20' , 'C20'],
['A21' , 'B21' , 'C21'],
['A22' , 'B22' , 'C22'],
['A23' , 'B23' , 'C23'],
['A24' , 'B24' , 'C24'],
['A25' , 'B25' , 'C25'],
['A26' , 'B26' , 'C26'],
['A27' , 'B27' , 'C27'],
['A28' , 'B28' , 'C28'],
['A29' , 'B29' , 'C29'],
['A30' , 'B30' , 'C30'],
['A31' , 'B31' , 'C31'],
['A32' , 'B32' , 'C32'],
['A33' , 'B33' , 'C33'],
['A34' , 'B34' , 'C34'],
['A35' , 'B35' , 'C35'],
['A36' , 'B36' , 'C36'],
['A37' , 'B37' , 'C37'],
['A38' , 'B38' , 'C38'],
['A39' , 'B39' , 'C39'],
['A40' , 'B40' , 'C40'],
['A41' , 'B41' , 'C41'],
];

$pdf->openpage;
$pdf->setAddTextPos( 50, 50  );
$table->addTable( $data, 400 );   # 400 is table width

$pdf->saveAs( 'table.pdf' );
```

Result: pdf generated with 2 pages.
at continuity of page missing a row data.
Note: i'm facing issue to attach a span shot of result.

Issues is: missing a row data. missing a row with data [A37, B37, C37].

Please help me in fixing this issues.
Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: Is there any otherway to create a pdf file to display the report in table format. or is there is any chance of converting excel file to pdf to display the report in table format. Please help me in fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

well, when I run your code I get

```
  commandPrompt > ./makepdf.pl 

    Useless use of greediness modifier '?' in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(\S{20}? <-- HERE )(?=\S)/ at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/PDF/Table.pm line 386.
    !!! Warning: !!! Incorrect Table Geometry! Setting bottom margin to end of sheet!
     at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/PDF/Report/Table.pm line 94.
    !!! Warning: !!! Incorrect Table Geometry! Setting bottom margin to end of sheet!
     at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/PDF/Report/Table.pm line 94.
```

I would think that

> Setting bottom margin to end of sheet!

and

```
!!! Warning: !!! Incorrect Table Geometry!
```

would have something to do with it.